# android programming UI troubles

Tags: android

I'm running into a UI problem and seeking help, advice on how to over come my problem.  I'm doing a lot of imaging

**1st problem**

When I touch an image I want it to draw over the current images but it's drawing under them, I know this because i comment out the UI just to see if I was correct and I am just cant think of a good way to fix this.

**2nd problem**

is touched events over lapping, when the UI screen from my 1st problem there is also a button and that button overlaps another event. how would I separate these 2 events so they exist in the same area but only trigger the one?

```
class GameScreen extends Screen {

    Board board;
    Player turn;

    enum GameState {

        Running,
        GameOver
    }
    GameState state = GameState.Running;

    public GameScreen(Game game) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        super(game);
        board = new Board();
    }

    public void update(float deltaTime) {

        List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();
        game.getInput().getKeyEvents();


        if (state == GameState.Running) {
            updateRunning(touchEvents, deltaTime);
        }
        if (state == GameState.GameOver) {
            updateGameOver(touchEvents);
        }
    }

    private void updateRunning(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents, float deltaTime) {
       
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
            }


            //Touch events
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN) {
                if (event.x > 5 && event.x < 65 && event.y > 90 && event.y < 170) {
                    buyCard(board.turn.hero);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void updatePaused(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {
    }

    private void updateGameOver(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {
    }

    @Override
    public void present(float deltaTime) {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

        if (state == GameState.Running) {
            drawRunningUI();
        }

        if (state == GameState.GameOver) {
            //drawGameOverUI();
        }




    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    void drawBoard() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

        drawSetup();
        drawVillain();
        drawHand();
        drawLineup();



    }

    void buyCard(Card card) {
        String n = card.name;
        n = "buy" + n;
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        g.drawPixmap(Assets.shade, 0, 0);//main deck
        g.drawPixmap(Assets.c.get(n), 135, 5);

        g.drawPixmap(Assets.back, 45, 90);
        if ("superpower".equals(card.type) || "equipment".equals(card.type)
                || "villain".equals(card.type) || "supervillain".equals(card.type)
                || "location".equals(card.type) || "hero".equals(card.type)) {
            g.drawPixmap(Assets.buy, 350, 90);
        }


    }

    void drawVillain() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        g.drawPixmap(board.superVillain.deck[0].pic, 330, 90);//villain
        g.drawPixmap(board.turn.hero.pic, 5, 90);// super hero
    }

    void drawLineup() {
        int x = 70;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
            g.drawPixmap(Assets.punch, x, 5);
            x = x + 65;
        }
    }

    void drawSetup() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        g.drawPixmap(Assets.battle, 0, 0);
        g.drawPixmap(Assets.kick, 200, 90);
        g.drawPixmap(Assets.weakness, 265, 90);

        g.drawPixmap(Assets.smallcard, 5, 5);//main deck
        g.drawPixmap(Assets.smallcard, 415, 130); //discard
        g.drawPixmap(Assets.smallcard, 415, 45);

    }

    void drawHand() {
        int x = 70;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
            g.drawPixmap(board.turn.deck.deck[i].pic, x, 230);
            x = x + 65;
        }

    }

    private void drawRunningUI() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        drawSetup();
        drawVillain();
        drawHand();
        drawLineup();

        //buyCard();
    }

    private void drawGameOverUI() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

try this.